# Can I use not only... but also... with two different subjects?

Tags: sentence-construction

As in this sentence:

> Not only should you cook your meals, but also they should be healthy.

The first subject is "you", and the second subject is "meals". Can I use `not only... but also...` this way? Otherwise what's the best way to connect the two parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. *Not only . . . but also* assumes parallel subjects.

The best way to connect them, in the example you gave, is simply to drop the *also:*

> Not only should you cook your meals, but they should be healthy.

Alternatively, you could rewrite it to make the subjects parallel:

> Not only should your meals be cooked by you, but they should also be healthy.

There you're getting into the passive voice, though, which a lot of people like to avoid. Personally, I would avoid it here, simply because it's too wordy.

One more possibility, again trying to make the subjects parallel:

> Not only should you cook your meals, but you should make them healthy.

Slight change in meaning, but works better.

Comment: Check your second quote. I think you meant be* not by:) otherwise excellent answer.

Comment: Do you disagree that *but they should also be healthy* as in my answer sounds good? Seems like something I would say, but I'm curious what you think.

Comment: I am curious about @Element115's question too .

Comment: I do think it sounds better that way, which is why I worded it that way in my second example. But i think that keeping the _also_ in there at all means that the subjects really should be parallel.

Comment: Excellent explanation, and thanks for acknowledging the other answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well technically you **can**, but I think it sounds more flowing and connected if you say

> Not only should you cook your meals, but they should also be healthy.

Putting the **also** right after the **but** sounds abrupt and choppy to my ear.